# TemplateDoesNotExist at / but filesystem loader says it does | happening in an extends tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.5.1 with Python 2.6.6.

The error that I am getting is `TemplateDoesNotExist at /` when using the template extends `{% extends "t_base_menu.html" %}`

t_base_menu.html is in `project/templates/t_base_menu.html`

The template that holds the extends is in the `project/home/templates/home/index.html`.

The loader setting are (SITE_ROOT is correct):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

In the error page the Template-loader postmortem says it exists, using django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:

---

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/project/templates/t_base_menu.html (File exists)

---

I have noticed that it is working if I move the t_base_menu.html to the `project/home/templates` folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have it working after moving the template, what's the issue?

Comment: This is only 1 app that uses this structure from about 10. It seems also weird to me that it works only in the app/templates dir, not in app/templates/app, where are the other html files. The app was previously deployed on other machine and it worked.

Comment: If it's in an app directory `app/templates/app` then the correct path would be `app/t_base_menu.html`. Including the prefix in the app template directories helps to prevent conflict, you need to include it in the template path

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that t_base_menu.html is in ```project/templates/t_base_menu.html``` and the file that extends is ```project/app/templates/app/index.html```.